# add previously calculated data to new data that is generated every time UIButton is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have 3 main pieces of data that I'm working on: 
 damageExp,
 startingAttackLevel,
 currentAttackLevel.

When the UIButton Attack is pressed, damageExp is gained then added to the startingAttackLevel resulting in the currentAttackLevel.

Now what I want to do is whenever the button is pressed again to add the newest damageExp gained and add it to the previous currentAttackLevel, to create a newCurrentLevel and so on and so forth.

I have created a class called Enemy and a method called `attack()`. But I just don't know and what to do to save the current data and then be able to hit the UIButton again and add the latest xp to the previous currentAttackLevel.

This is probably very simple, but I don't know what I need to know.

**This is my Class Enemy.swift**

```
class Enemy  {
     var healthLevel = 100

    func health() {
       print("You currently have \(healthLevel) health")
    }

    func move(steps: Int) -> String {
        return "Walk forward \(steps) paces"
    }

    func attack() {
        let startingAttackLevel: Float = 10.0
        var currentAttackLevel: Float = 10.0
        var attackStrength = currentAttackLevel
        var attackRoll = Float.random(in: 0.0...((currentAttackLevel * 0.20) + currentAttackLevel))
        var attackDamage = attackRoll * attackStrength
        var damageExp: Float = 0.0

        if attackRoll > (currentAttackLevel - (currentAttackLevel * 0.20)) && attackRoll < ((currentAttackLevel * 0.20) + currentAttackLevel) {
            damageExp = currentAttackLevel * 0.30
            currentAttackLevel = damageExp + startingAttackLevel

        } else if attackRoll > (currentAttackLevel - (currentAttackLevel * 0.60)) && attackRoll < (currentAttackLevel - (currentAttackLevel * 0.20)){
            damageExp = currentAttackLevel * 0.15
           currentAttackLevel = damageExp + startingAttackLevel

        } else if attackRoll > 0.0 && attackRoll < (currentAttackLevel - (currentAttackLevel * 0.60)){
            damageExp = currentAttackLevel * 0.06
            currentAttackLevel = damageExp + startingAttackLevel
        }

        print("You roll a \(String(format: "%.0f", attackRoll)). You do a total damage of \(String(format: "%.1f", attackDamage)) damage. ")
        print("You have gained a total amount of \(damageExp) xp")
        print("Your are currently level \(currentAttackLevel)")
    }
}
```

**This below is from my viewController.swift** **Remember my Enemy() Class is = to my constant skeleton**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let skeleton = Enemy()

    @IBOutlet weak var mainTextLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func walkForward(_ sender: UIButton) {

        print(skeleton.move(steps: Int.random(in: 0...50)))

    }

    @IBAction func attack(_ sender: UIButton) {

        skeleton.health()
        skeleton.attack()

    }
}
```

Comment: Make currentAttackLevel an instance variable. Move its declaration/initialization below healthLevel.

Comment: @Don I was so close.

I had to do what you suggested moving the currentAttackLevel out of the method changing its declaration location. I also had to change the if statements from what I originally posted to 

currentAttackLevel = damageExp + currentAttackLevel

In summary from what I understand, when the if statement fires it redefines the currentAttackLevel variable which is then stored at the variable declaration. Is this correct?

Comment: That's correct. Before, you were creating a new currentAttackLevel and setting its initial value to 10 every time you called skeleton.attack(). It went out of scope at the end of the method. When you create an instance variable, it holds its value as long as the instance exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code -

```
class Enemy  {
static let initialHealthValueConstant : Float = 100.0

let initialHealthLevel : Float = Enemy.initialHealthValueConstant
var currentHealthLevel : Float

init(with currentHealthLevel : Float) {
    self.currentHealthLevel = currentHealthLevel
}

convenience init() {
    self.init(with: Enemy.initialHealthValueConstant)
}

func health() {
   print("You currently have \(currentHealthLevel) health")
}

func move(steps: Int) -> String {
    return "Walk forward \(steps) paces"
}

func attack() {
    let startingAttackLevel = currentHealthLevel
    var currentAttackLevel = currentHealthLevel
    let attackStrength = currentAttackLevel
    let attackRoll = Float.random(in: 0.0...((currentAttackLevel * 0.20) + currentAttackLevel))
    let attackDamage = attackRoll * attackStrength
    var damageExp: Float = 0.0

    if attackRoll > (currentAttackLevel - (currentAttackLevel * 0.20)) && attackRoll < ((currentAttackLevel * 0.20) + currentAttackLevel) {
        damageExp = currentAttackLevel * 0.30
        currentAttackLevel = damageExp + startingAttackLevel

    } else if attackRoll > (currentAttackLevel - (currentAttackLevel * 0.60)) && attackRoll < (currentAttackLevel - (currentAttackLevel * 0.20)){
        damageExp = currentAttackLevel * 0.15
       currentAttackLevel = damageExp + startingAttackLevel

    } else if attackRoll > 0.0 && attackRoll < (currentAttackLevel - (currentAttackLevel * 0.60)){
        damageExp = currentAttackLevel * 0.06
        currentAttackLevel = damageExp + startingAttackLevel
    }

    currentHealthLevel = currentAttackLevel
    print("You roll a \(String(format: "%.0f", attackRoll)). You do a total damage of \(String(format: "%.1f", attackDamage)) damage. ")
    print("You have gained a total amount of \(damageExp) xp")
    print("Your are currently level \(currentAttackLevel)")
}
}
```

Also, you don't need these two extra variables - currentAttackLevel, startingAttackLevel. You can use currentHealthLevel in place of them.